# Mongo DB Realm + Kotlin Coroutines - Cannot find a version of 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core' that satisfies the version constraints

Tags: android, mongodb, kotlin, realm

I'm trying to use Mongo DB Realm in my Android app. I've added those two dependencies:

> ```
> implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0-native-mt"
> implementation "io.realm.kotlin:library-sync:1.0.2"
> ```

Along with the plugin:

> ```
> id 'io.realm.kotlin'
> ```

and

> ```
> id 'io.realm.kotlin' version '1.0.2' apply false
> ```

But I'm getting this strange error, and not sure why exactly..

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Cannot find a version of
> 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core' that satisfies the
> version constraints:
> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically due to a conflict between library versions. The solution is to specify the code down below.

```
implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0-native-mt") {
        version {
            strictly("1.6.0-native-mt")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of kotlin that your IDE use?
Try to upgrade to latest version of kotlin

Comment: 212-1.7.10-release-333-AS5457.46
The latest, but still getting the same erorr.